# Importing a DSA key from xml string fails for one user. Permissions? Broken installation? Bad KSP?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, cryptoapi, dsa

A user recently reported a weird error when using my software. I use DSA signatures to verify licenses. When the software imports the public key to verify a signature, the DSA provider's [FromXmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsa.fromxmlstring.aspx) method throws a **CryptographicException** with the description "*Key not valid for use in specified state.*"

It would appear that the _OpenCSP method called from System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle returns a NTE_BAD_KEY_STATE (0x8009000b). This is the first time anyone has reported this error to me, and that code has not changed for years.

What are the likely causes of this? A masked permissions error? A broken CAPI installation? Blocked by .net trust/permissions settings? Junk stored by a key storage provider, or a KSP returning something unexpected to cryptoapi?

I have googled the error code/description/etc but didn't come across any real answers as to what might cause this...

An isolated version of the code that fails is here:
http://forum.huagati.com/getattachment.ashx?fileid=78

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Reflection;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    try
    {
      string key = "<DSAKeyValue><P>wrjxUnfKvH/1s5cbZ48vuhTjflRT5PjOFnr9GeUPZSIoZhYATYtME4JRKrXBtSkyioRNtE1xgghbGAyvAJ5jOWw88fLBF+P1ilsZyq72G1YcbB+co8ImQhAbWKmdCicO9/66Th2MB+7kms/oY3NaCzKEuR7J3b23dGrFpp4ccMM=</P><Q>xmxoSErIJCth91A3dSMjC6yQCu8=</Q><G>bwOLeEaoJHwSiC3i3qk9symlG/9kfzcgrkhRSWHqWhyPAfzqdV1KxJboMpeRoMoFr2+RqqKHgcdbzOypmTeN4QI/qh4nSsl5iEfVerarBOrFuRdOVcJO0d8WE233XQznd1K66nXa5L8d9SNZrM6umZ1YuBjhVsTFdPlIXKfGYhk=</G><Y>wZnEEdMUsF3U3NBQ8ebWHPOp37QRfiBn+7h5runN3YDee1e9bC7JbJf+Uq0eQmU8zDs+avEgD68NpxTKEHGr4nQ3rW6qqacj5SDbwO7nI6eN3wWrVhvrWcQm0tUO93m64HsEJREohfoL+LjqgrqIjZVT4D1KXE+k/iAb6WKAsIA=</Y><J>+zmcCCNm2kn1EXH9T45UcownEe7JH+gl3Lw2lhVzXuX/dYp5sGCA2lK119iQ+m3ogjOuwABATCVFLo6J66DsSlMd0I8WSD5WKPvypQ7QjY0Iv71J2N0FW0ZXpMlk/CE8zq4Z7arM1N564mNe</J><Seed>QDrZrUFowquY5Uay8YtUFOXnv28=</Seed><PgenCounter>Gg==</PgenCounter></DSAKeyValue>";

      DSACryptoServiceProvider csp2 = new DSACryptoServiceProvider();
      csp2.FromXmlString(key);

      Console.WriteLine("Success!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      int hResult = 0;
      try
      {
          PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Exception).GetProperty("HResult", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
          hResult = (int)pi.GetValue(ex, null);
      }
      catch (Exception ex2)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("HResult lookup failed: " + ex2.ToString());
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Initializing CSP failed: " + ex.ToString() + "\r\nHResult: " + hResult.ToString("x"));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress Enter to continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

...and on the affected user's machine it returns:

```
Initializing CSP failed: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Ke
y not valid for use in specified state.

at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters paramete
rs, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.get_StaticDssProvHandle()
at System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(DSA
Parameters parameters)
at System.Security.Cryptography.DSA.FromXmlString(String xmlString)
at Test.Main()
HResult: 8009000b
```

**Update:** The same code works fine when running under .net fx 2.0 on the same machine, but fails under .net fx 4.0.

**Update 2:** It appears that the DSA provider looks for keys stored under %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\DSS\[SID] even then initializing with an existing key. Could there be a conflict with this mechanism? Anyone know more about how that key storage thing operates, and why it is hit when loading a public key from a string?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The problem, which you describe, seems very interesting to me, but without some additional information and some experiments it is difficult definitively to say what is the reason. So I'll try to describe how I understand the problem.

First of all .NET cryptography classes use internally the unmanaged CryptoAPI. So the method `_OpenCSP` call internally [CryptAcquireContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379886(VS.85).aspx) function. In its the documentation we can read following about the error `NTE_BAD_KEY_STATE` (0x8009000BL):

> The user password has changed since
> the private keys were encrypted.

Users **private** keys used by DSA provider are saved as files in the directory `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\DSS\[SID]` and will be encrypted with relatively sophisticated algorithm about which you can read [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309408). Important to understand that the files from the directory corresponds to the key containers of user's keys. Typically the user has full access to the files in the file system. The files will be encrypted with the key which depends on the user's password. In many standard cases the files will be re-encrypted after the password change, but the recovery algorithm depends on many things. If the password was *reset* instead of the changing by the user itself (e.g. reset by a domain administrator/account operator and so on), the old contents of the directory `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\DSS\[SID]` could become useless. For example if the user is not an Active Directory user (a local user) and the local administrator resets his password then the problem with crypto-containers will occur.

So the first suggestion would be to ask the user whether his Active Directory password was reset. Next you should verify that the directory `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\DSS\[SID]` exists in the user's profile and the user has full access to the directory in the file system. Then you should delete all files from the directory (creating previously the backup copy of the files). By the way it is interesting to know whether the user has a centrally saved profile (saved on the server). If it has central profile one can verify that the same problem, which you describe, exists on the other computer for the user and another user would have no problems on his original computer.

One more question which is not quite clear for me is **why** the key container from the the directory `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\DSS\[SID]` are used at all because you use only **public keys**. In CryptoAPI one should use `CryptAcquireContext` with `NULL` as `pszContainer` parameter and `CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT` in `dwFlags`. I am not sure that .NET use the `CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT` flag and it could be indirect your problem.

You can create `DSACryptoServiceProvider` with [the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be60ks99.aspx) having [CspParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.aspx) parameter. [CspParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.aspx) on the other side has [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.flags.aspx) property which is extended in .NET 4.0 with the value [CreateEphemeralKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspproviderflags.aspx). The description of `CspProviderFlags.CreateEphemeralKey` is very close to the description of the `CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT` flag of the `CryptAcquireContext` function. So use can try to use [CspProviderFlags.CreateEphemeralKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspproviderflags.aspx) or `CspProviderFlags.CreateEphemeralKey` together with `CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer` (`NULL` as `pszContainer` parameter of `CryptAcquireContext` means also default key container).

Moreover, if it is possible, you can try to debug the problem on the computer where the problem can be reproduced. For debugging you can use .NET sources which can be enabled (see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/downloadsetup.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx)) or **downloaded** from [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx). You can then answer on some questions about the values of `CspParameters` which currently used in your program and compare the values for .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0.

If what I wrote will not help to solve the problem, please could you amend your question with additional information:

- Which operating system version and which service pack has the computer where the problem can be reproduced?
- Is the problem user dependent? I mean: do other users the same computer have the same problem?
- Does the the problem exist with a domain (active directory) user or with a local user account? Has the user with the issue a centrally saved user profile which is saved on the server? If he has, than can the problem can be reproduced also on the other computers by the user?
- Could you describe a little more the environment in which situation you use the public key verification? Especially does the program run in the security context of the current user or do you use impersonation?

**UPDATED**: After reading of the forum where the problem originally was posted, I become pessimistic about solving of the problem. If you have no direct contact to the computer where the problem could be reproduced and the communication with the only user who has the problem are done only per posting in the forum... Nevertheless I have been thinking about the problem and so I decided to try to reproduce the problem myself. And I had success in this. So I'll describe here my results carefully. I'll describe how the can reproduce the problem so that it looks exactly like it is described in [the forum thread](http://forum.huagati.com/topic167-standardize-linq-to-sql-class-and-names-failed.aspx).

You should do the following steps:

1. You create a local test account on your computer.
2. You login with the test account and generate the default key container for the DSA provider. You can do this for example with respect of the small .NET program which call following simple function:

   ```
    static string GenerateDsaKeyInDefaultContainer()
    {
        const int PROV_DSS_DH = 13;
        CspParameters cspParam = new CspParameters(PROV_DSS_DH);
        cspParam.KeyContainerName = null;
        cspParam.KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Signature;
        cspParam.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;
        DSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new DSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParam);
        return csp.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName;
    }
   ```

the function returns the name of the file which will be created in the directory `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\DSS\[SID]` and which will contain the generated key pair.
3) You logout the test account and login with an another account which has local administrative rights. You reset the password of the test account.
4) You login one more time with the test account and verify that the test program, which you posted, compiled in Visual Studio 2010 for .NET 4.0 produces the error `NTE_BAD_KEY_STATE` (0x8009000b) and the corresponding exception will be thrown.
5) If you recompile the program for .NET 3.5 instead of .NET 4.0 (you can use Visual Studio 2010 also) the test program will be run without any errors.

So all results will be exactly like there are described in [the forum thread](http://forum.huagati.com/topic167-standardize-linq-to-sql-class-and-names-failed.aspx).

If you delete or renamed the file with the default key container for the DSA provider the problem will be solved. Like I described before after resetting of the users password the contain of the default key container will be unable to be decrypted. So if you know the name of the default container which is unique for the user (you can see the name for example from the traces of the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)) you can just copy any key container file from any other user and any other computer to the directory `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\DSS\[SID]`, rename the file so that the name will be the default container name and ... you will have absolutely the same results like with the resetting of the users password.

I made some experiments with different settings of the `CspParameters` as the parameter of `DSACryptoServiceProvider` (see my first suggestions about the usage of [CspProviderFlags.CreateEphemeralKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspproviderflags.aspx)), but without any success. After that I debugged the source code of .NET 4.0 and can definitively say that the call of `_OpenCSP` function, which code is not opened, will be called with the parameters which are **independent** from the parameters of the `DSACryptoServiceProvider` constructor. So one can not find a workaround of the problem for .NET 4.0 in the way with different settings of the `CspParameters` as the parameter of `DSACryptoServiceProvider`.

So if you want to modify your code so that it should work also in the situation with the corrupted default key provider I see currently only 2 ways to solve the problem:

1. Implement the whole or the part of code using unmanaged `CryptAcquireContext` function with the `CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT` flag.
2. Detect the problem with the error `NTE_BAD_KEY_STATE` (0x8009000b) and include the code part which delete or temporary renamed the file from `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\DSS\[SID]` which contains the corrupted default key container. To detect the name of the file I think you can try to use `CryptGetProvParam` function with the `PP_UNIQUE_CONTAINER` or/and `PP_ENUMCONTAINERS` parameters.

I am sorry for the long text of my answer and thanks to all who are able to read it till this place. :-)

I hope that my answer do help you KristoferA to solve the problem and improve software which you develop.

Comment: Re. the public-private: yes, that raised my eyebrows as well. Using the sample code in my question and Sysinternals' ProcMon you can see that even when just importing a public key, CryptoAPI will go off and hit the key store. That happens on my own system too, but doesn't cause any errors here. Just interesting to see...

Comment: I have asked the user for more details and to use procmon on his system to see if that can reveal any underlying errors, e.g. permission errors etc, but haven't heard back from him yet. The forum thread where the problem was originally reported is here: http://forum.huagati.com/topic167-standardize-linq-to-sql-class-and-names-failed.aspx

Comment: @KristoferA - Huagati.com: I read the thread from the forum and after some experiments I could reproduce/simulate the described problem. See more in the "updated" part of my answer.

Comment: @Oleg: Excellent, thanks a lot for the exhaustive research and excellent answer. The goal was to find what causes this, and if it is something that is likely to affect other users then provide a proper error message, fallback, or workaround for users. Your answer has provided me with that; password resets are not uncommon so although it has only been reported by one user it is very likely that others have experienced it. Knowing this, as a workaround I can simply pop up a dialog or messagebox providing the user with the information they need to work around this... +1 !

Comment: @KristoferA - Huagati.com: You welcome! And thanks for the good words.

Comment: +1 Crazy answer. Sorry for ruining the nice round 64 upvotes :)

Comment: @FreshCode: You welcome! For some years I spend many time to study how one can use CryptoAPI and how it works internally. I don't really used the knowledge. So I am glad to find such questions like this. I am also glad that so many people found my answer interesting or helpful. Thanks for you and for all for read and upvote my answer.